# Improving my credit score in the US: do I need to use the credit card?

Tags: usa, financial

I live in the US and have a credit card as well as a debit card. In order to improve my credit score, should I use my credit card or my debit card? (assume that both cards are never in the red)

Comment: 2 downvotes on this question and not a single comment? No wonder why there is nobody on this SE.

Comment: This is off-topic, as it's not about an issue a local wouldn't have as well. You probably have better luck getting an aswer for this on [money.SE](http://money.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Then migrate the question instead of downvoting. And how about the other questions on credit history?

Comment: probably there is no reason of migrating this question to M.SE, as it would instantly be closed [as a duplicate](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/optimal-way-to-use-a-credit-card-to-build-better-credit).

Comment: Then just close the question instead of downvoting. I don't think it's a good way to welcome new visitors.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt, you can delete your question here. I deleted a number of mine. Hopefully you'll find something useful from money.SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use your credit card, as building credit history isn't simply about having the credit card, it's about responsibly *using* it, meaning making purchases and paying them off in the appropriate time period. Best of luck!